# Run underscore code on click

Tags: underscore.js

I have the following the underscore code which displays products, I was wondering if there were a way to run this code when the user clicks an anchor link, in this case `a.filter-btn` the reason being is because I would like to update the value of `ids` in `<% if(_.contains(ids, productTile.id)) {  %>` depending on the anchor link they click.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/template" class="template">
        <h2>POV</h2>

         <ul>
            <% _.each( rc , function(productTile) {  %>

            <% if(_.contains(ids, productTile.id)) {  %>

            <li class="productTile" data-id="<%= productTile.id %>">
               <img src="<%= productTile.images[0] %>" alt=""/>
               <h3>Demo<%= productTile["name"] %></h3>
              <p><%= productTile.price.formatted %></p>

            </li>           

            <% } %>
            <% }); %>


 </ul>




  </script>



   var listingTemplate = _.template(
          $( "script.template" ).html()
      );

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $( ".listingTemplate" ).append(
           listingTemplate(data.pl)
     );  
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="filter-btn">filter</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what i understand from your question. you can bind click event on your anchor this way using jQuery

```
$( ".filter-btn" ).click(function() {
   alert($( this ).text());
   $( ".listingTemplate" ).append(
           listingTemplate(data.pl)
     );
});
```

put this code in your `document.ready` method

Comment: thing is I'd also like to manipulate the value of ids within the underscore code, depending on the button they click.

Comment: you can access which element user clicks by using `this` inside anonymous function of `.click` you can add your logic accordingly

Comment: i have updated my answer, now it will print `filter` text of your anchor tag in alert box

Comment: ok, but I meant within the scropt.template code, I want to change the value of ids depending on what button they click.

Comment: <% if(_.contains(ids, productTile.id)) {  %>

Comment: you have to send a `JSON` object to your compiled template. i think you should go through this official documentation of templates before going any further http://underscorejs.org/#template